# Custom WPF Treeview

Tags: wpf, treeview

I'm trying to write a custom Treeview in WPF where child items are linked to their parents by lines.

It's hard to explain, but I'm basically trying to make a custom version of the below treeview so that our designer can customise it as required:

[Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGnWk.jpg)

Is there an easy way of doing this? So far I've been hacking away at it and haven't got very far.

Comment: P.s. I've tried creating a custom template using blend, but I still can't see how it would be possible to add this functionality to the control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an interesting problem.  I think that probably what you will need to do is create a custom control that subclasses `TreeViewItem` and add a couple of dependency properties that the parent class doesn't provide.

Since `TreeViewItem` inherits from `ItemsControl`, and not `Selector`, it doesn't have `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` properties.  Your custom control needs to implement these properties.  The tricky thing about this is setting `SelectedItem`:  it can be the item for which `IsSelected` is true, or it can be the item whose `Items` property contains an item for which `SelectedItem` is not null.  The `SelectedIndex` property needs to work the same way.

One other property that you're going to need - and I'm not sure how you calculate this - is the height of the line that's going to go into row 1, column 0 of the grid in the `TreeViewItem` template.  It may be possible to calculate this as a function of the `SelectedIndex` and the row's `ActualHeight`, which would be sweet because then you don't have to get involved with any of the details of how the control is rendered.

At any rate, once you have these properties, editing the control template to use them should be straightforward.   You have the circle around the expander triangle, which is only visible if `SelectedItem` is not null.  (Actually, it's a circle with a line descending to the bottom of the grid cell.)  You have the line extending from the circle to the left edge of the grid cell, which is visible if `SelectedItem` is not null and `Parent` not null.  You have the vertical line in row 1, column 0 of the grid, that again is only visible if `SelectedItem` is not null.

Then you have the elements that are displayed if `IsSelected` is true:  the horizontal line in the expander cell and the black arrow background.

That's not actually a crazy amount of work to get such a cool effect, I think.

Answer (score 0):

To customize a WPF TreeView a couple of things are important:

1. Use databinding to bind the nodes of the TreeView to ViewModel objects for the nodes
2. Make DataTemplates that match to the type of the ViewModel nodes

Josh Smith has a [good article on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) that explains all this and more.

Edit:

You can put a complete UserControl in a node that does anything that a UserControl can do.

Edit 2:

From the updated illustration, I would suggest creating a Style for the TreeView.  DataTemplates only apply to individual item nodes within the tree.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I followed the article you linked to, but unless I'm mistaken, it didn't mention the type of customisation I'm after. I haven't added binding yet because I'm currently just trying to work with getting an appropriate template.

Comment: Perhaps if you give more explanation of what you are aiming for you someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Draw your requirement using any drawing tool and post that image.That will help your question to get more responses

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've edited the post to include an image of our actual requirement. Apologies for not doing so before, but I was worried it might be a bit cheeky.